# How to ignore "Application collection already exists" error?

Tags: plsql, error-handling, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

How can I ignore the errors below?

> create_co - errc=-20104 errm=ORA-20104: create_collection_from_query_b Error:ORA-20101: Application collection exists
>
> create_co - errc=-20104 errm=ORA-20104: create_collection_from_queryb2 Error:ORA-00001: Schending van UNIQUE-beperking (APEX_180200.WWV_FLOW_COLLECTIONS_UK).

This error is confusing for users.

```
declare
  pl_query                varchar2(4000);
  cl_collectie   constant varchar2(255) := 'MY_COLLECTION';
begin
  --
  if apex_collection.collection_exists( p_collection_name => cl_collectie )
  then
    apex_collection.delete_collection( p_collection_name => cl_collectie );
  end if;
  --
  pl_query := q'[select QUERY]' ;
  --       
  apex_collection.create_collection_from_queryb2( p_collection_name => cl_collectie
                                                , p_query => pl_query );
end;
```

We're using Application Express 18.2.0.00.12.

Comment: How are you running that code? Page submit? Dynamic Action? Since you delete the collection before creating it again the user shouldn't be seeing that error. Probably the users ate hitting the button that generate the collection while it's still running if this is the case one way to solve the problem is to disable the button during code execution.

Answer (score 1):

if you run the dynamic action for example on button click then you have to disable the button until the dynamic action is finished. generally you need to find a way to prevent your users from running the dynamic action a second time if the first time isn't finished yet.